# Using jQuery to replace textbox with <textarea> after certain character length

Tags: jquery, html, keypress

I'm using the simple code below to replace a textbox (`<input type=text />`) with a `<textarea>` element after the user types in a certain number of characters. In the example below, this takes place after the 10th character.  The code works, except that the contents of the `<textarea>` omits the 10th character that the user typed.   For example, if you type "testing 1234" in the textbox, the textarea will omit the "4".  Any ideas?  Thanks.  --Jake

```
    $('.info').keypress(function() {
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    if (count > 10)
    {
        var contents = $(this).val();
        $(this).after('<textarea></textarea>').next().val(contents).end().remove()
    }
})
```

UPDATE:
I tried the suggestion many of you shared: using the keyup event.  It works, but only if you type slowly.  If you're a fast typer, like I suspect most people here would be, the 10th character is still omitted when using the keyup event.

Comment: Seriously, I would just go with @Neil's solution. It's not gonna be very hard, and it should solve all your problems.

Comment: I'd go with a solution that works if you paste something into the box.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you should use textarea from the start, augmenting "rows" attribute only.  I'd be willing to bet you'd maintain all your characters after the change and it would behave exactly like a textbox with rows="1".

```
$('.info').keypress(function() {
    var count = this.value.length;
    if (this.rows == 1 && count > 10)
    {
        this.rows = 4;  // Or whatever you'd prefer.
    }
});
```

Comment: Ooo, that's a really good idea. Didn't see it until I'd finished posting my idea (the posts were only 20 seconds apart!). :)

Comment: That could definitely be an option.  If I can't figure out how to do what I'm currently attempting, I'll definitely take your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't even need to manipulate the rows. Just set the height with css.

Comment: Good point.  I suppose it depends on how he wants to use it though.

Comment: Your solution ended up being the best.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Line 1 (notice the argument):

```
$('.info').keypress(function(e) {
```

Line 5:

```
    var contents = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, because I haven't tested the code! But don't tell anyone! ;)

Comment: It turns out this fix did not work in Chrome.  So I went with a different fix instead.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155403/using-jquery-to-replace-textbox-with-textarea-after-certain-character-length/4155431#4155431) is probably the best approach.  However, if you want to go ahead replacing the input with a textarea, you can use jQuery's [*replaceWith()*](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) (suggested in patrick_dw's now deleted answer), but you should avoid using events like *keyup*.

The HTML5 `oninput` event was designed to handle all sorts of text input, like pasting, dragging and dropping, spell checker corrections, etc.

```
$('.info').on('input', function() {
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    if (count > 10) {
        $(this).replaceWith('<textarea>', {value: this.value});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the event to `keyup` instead of `keypress`.

Comment: keyup doesn't fix the the issue.  See the update to my post above.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: In that case, go with Neil's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `keyup` instead of `keypress`? That triggers the action after the key is released (and the character has been typed).

Comment: keyup doesn't fix the the issue.  See the update to my post above.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the keyup event

```
$('.info').keyup(function() {
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    if (count > 10)
    {
        var contents = $(this).val();
        $(this).after('<textarea></textarea>').next().val(contents).end().remove()
    }
})
```

Comment: keyup doesn't fix the the issue.  See the update to my post above.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When the event is handled by your function the character has not been entered into the box. Look at the event object passed to the javascript function and append the character that triggered it.

Comment: Use a combination of mine and Andy E's suggestions. keyup is the wrong way to go. replacewith is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Keypress use keyup. that way it allows change for the typed data to be inserted before the change happens to a text area. this should stop the last char from being dropped

Comment: keyup doesn't fix the the issue.  See the update to my post above.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using keyup instead of keypress. But I think what Neil suggested is a better approach.

Comment: keyup doesn't fix the the issue.  See the update to my post above.  Thanks anyway.